# How to create a list of sequential numbers when created from "for in" looping?

Tags: python, json, csv

```
import requests
def trigger():
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}

    with open("SofaScore_Live.csv", "w+", newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        titlemenu = "id" + "\n"
        f.write(titlemenu)
        url = f'https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/sport/football/events/live'
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
        events = response['events']
        for event in events:
            try:
                if event['hasEventPlayerStatistics']:
                    description = event['status']['description']
                    if description == 'Halftime':
                        pass
                    else:
                        id = event['id']
                        row = str(id) + "\n"
                        f.write(row)
            except:
                pass
        f.close()
```

When importing game ID's via JSON API, the example result is as follows:

```
id
8464
7936
1657
2647
```

But I would like to create a column with the numbers in sequence to make it easier to see the number of lines, looking like this:

```
id     row
8464   1
7936   2
1657   3
2647   4
```

How could I generate this column taking advantage of each of the looping in `for event in events:`?

Comment: you could look into pandas dataframe, which is basically just a table with columns

Comment: the builtin function `enumerate()` will give you a tuple with the ordinal and your `id` (btw, that's not a good choice for a name since you're overwriting another builtin function)

Comment: Hi @gimix, in that case I could work with it by setting it to ```enum = enumerate()``` and to register in CSV as ```f.write(id + "," + enum)```? Or did I misunderstand the statement? Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to do `for i, event in enumerate(events):`

Comment: Thanks to tip @SembeiNorimaki, solved my problem perfectly, if anyone can create an answer for me to put the question as solved I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we suggested in comments, the solution is:

```
for i, event in enumerate(events):
```

and then

```
f.write(id + "," + i)
```